# How to plot an osm file with sf?

Tags: r, openstreetmap

I am trying to use `plot_sf` to plot shapefile from openstreemap, but I get a blank plot. Here is what I am trying:

```
library("osmdata")
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright
bb <- getbb("Sevilla")
q <- opq(bb)
q <- q %>% add_osm_feature(key = "highway", value = "motorway")
q1 <- opq_string(q)
dt <- osmdata_sf(q1)
sf::plot_sf(dt$osm_lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Pretty much the same as yours:

```
library(osmdata)
library(sf)
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright
bb <- getbb("Sevilla")
q <- opq(bb)
q <- q %>% add_osm_feature(key = "highway", value = "motorway")
q1 <- opq_string(q)
dt <- osmdata_sf(q1)
plot(dt)
dt$osm_lines
plot(dt$osm_lines)
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I used `plot` instead of `plot_sf`. I'll have another look.

Comment: I get an error with plot `error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'`

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the documentation of the `sf` or `osmdata` packages that uses `plot_sf`. Could you use `plot` instead?